# Imacro SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT error

Tags: imacros

Can't save screenshot of the Element...

Here is code:

```
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\img\ FILE=screen.png WAIT=YES
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:adcopy-puzzle-image  CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawWindow does not implement interface Window., line 21 (Error code: -1001)
```

Couldn't find anything in web. This error was reported only on ScreenGrab add-on.

Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.

I had firefox developer edition and that was causing problems... after reinstalling normal firefox it worked perfectly.